# Camel Route on Fuse Taking up a lot of TCP Connections

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I am working on an enterprise application within Fuse and I'm running into an issue when the application tries to connect to ActiveMQ:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://abc:61616. Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
```

After some investigation on the box, it turns out the Camel routes we've have deployed are taking up sometimes thousands of TCP connections which might be preventing other connections, causing the error.

However, based on what the route is doing, I wouldn't have expect it to use thousands of TCP connections to do the job. Does the way Camel and ActiveMQ communicate naturally spawn this many connections or should I see this as a major problem and investigate?

Comment: No, that's not natural at all. Here's my broker url string which uses failover, i'm not sure if this is helpful or not: `failover:(tcp://abc:61611,tcp://def:61611)`. Log for errors in all the log files, particularly for the connection pools - there are likely other hints in those logs (karaf.log, xyz.log, etc).

Comment: And if you are using connection pooling, please provide the configuration for this if you can.

Comment: Are you starting a new route (or a new Camel context) for each message?  That's a nice anti-pattern that will quickly run you out of threads...

Comment: Yeah post the the route please you might be leaking connections. I had a database connection leak due some late night coding which drove me insane for a couple of hours so your problem is probably due to a small error somewhere.